# Transitioning background images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to adapt some code I found on youtube and ran into some trouble.  I can switch through images fine, but I can't seem to adapt the code to transition through background images.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</body>            
</html>
```

and

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
}

body {
    background-image:url("Summer.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and

```
//JavaScript Document

var myImage=document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var imageArray=["Summer.jpg", "Autumn.jpg", "Winter.jpg"];

var imageIndex=0;

function changeImage () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage=myImage;
    myImage.setAttribute("url", imageArray [ imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
        }
    }

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,2000);
```

I am a complete novice here so if I am missing something obvious, please point me in the right direction to read up on it.  Thanks.

Comment: Now that it works, is there any way to make the change a smoother transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage=myImage;
myImage.setAttribute("url", imageArray [ imageIndex]);
```

do

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageArray[imageIndex] + ")";
```

Comment: Perfect. It makes sense and it works. I can't ask for more than that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the backgroundImage property of the body's style to the appropriate "url(...)" syntax.  Replace your `changeImage` function with this one:

```
function changeImage () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageArray[imageIndex] + ")";
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
        }
    }
```

What you were doing with `myImage.setAttribute` wouldn't work because `myImage` isn't a DOM element and doesn't have a `setAttribute` method.